# How to populate an object property in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this in DB:

```
[{
  _id: Objectid('7889000--'),
  content: {
    payload: {
      user: ObjectId('88799900')
    }
  }
}]
```

I want to populate the user key in that object but is not working. Here is what I am doing:

```
Model.find({}).populate('content.payload.user')
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the mongoose schema's? or at least the relevant fields and refs

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.exec()` after you populate.
So your code should become this:

```
Model.find({}).populate('content.payload.user').exec((err, user)=>{
//your code here
})
```